# Android: Long-Click text on button

Tags: android, button, text, long-click

In my android-app I'm trying to create a button with two lines of text. One will display what the button is doing when (short) clicked, the other one should show the effect when long-clicked and that the button can be long-clicked. Just like on the the standerd keyboard of the android system (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWdzt.png)).

What i've tried:

```
Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(64, 24, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas imageCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
Paint imagePaint = new Paint();
imagePaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
imagePaint.setTextSize(14f);
imageCanvas.drawText(String, pxwidth/2, pxheight, imagePaint);
image = new BitmapDrawable(canvasBitmap);
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.button)).setCompoundDrawables(null,image,null,null);
```

But it isn't suported at my currend API version (API 9 / GINGERBREAD / Android 2.3)
Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to target 9, then you can't use that function, and you'll need to use another technique.  One way I can think of is to use an ImageButton instead of a button, prerender the image of the entire button, and apply it to the new ImageButton in xml.

Comment: Yes that could be a solution, but since I have to use this on a lot of buttons this would involve a lot of pre-rederering and not very memory efficient.

Comment: Another suggestion then would be a custom view.  Subclass button and override onDraw and onMeasure, adding in extra room to draw your image and actually drawing it in onDraw

Comment: Can you give me an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

I used this `Custom View` as solution (with thanks to Gabe Sechan for the idea):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Button;

class LongClickButton extends Button {
    private String mLongClickString;
    private String mOnLongClick;
    private Paint mTextPaint;
    public LongClickButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);

        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(this.getTextSize()/2);
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        mTextPaint.setShadowLayer(0, 1, 1, Color.GRAY);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LongClickButton, 0, 0);
        try{
            mLongClickString = a.getString(R.styleable.LongClickButton_longClickText);
            mOnLongClick = a.getString(R.styleable.LongClickButton_onLongClick);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
    public String getLongClickString(){
        return mLongClickString;
    }
    public String getOnLongClick(){
        return mOnLongClick;
    }
    public void setLongClickString(String LongClickString){
        mLongClickString = LongClickString;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
    public void setOnLongClick(String OnLongClick){
        mOnLongClick = OnLongClick;
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawText(mLongClickString, this.getWidth()-(this.getPaddingRight()/4*3), (this.getPaddingTop()/2)+mTextPaint.getTextSize(), mTextPaint);
    }
}
```